# Invalid RGBA argument: array

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have searched in many forums for an answer to this question, but not found anything that works for me or fully answers the question of what the error means. Below is a reproducible example:

```
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
xTest = [.1,.2,.1]
yTest = [.1,.2,.1]
circleLabels = [0,1,0]
colormap = np.array(['r', 'b'])
colorVec = colormap[circleLabels]
plt.plot(xTest, yTest,"o",color = colorVec)
plt.xlabel('x coordinate')
plt.ylabel('y coordinate')
plt.title("scatterplot of circle points")
```

Which gives me the error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
~/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/IPython/core/formatters.py in __call__(self, obj)
    339                 pass
    340             else:
--> 341                 return printer(obj)
    342             # Finally look for special method names
    343             method = get_real_method(obj, self.print_method)

~/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/IPython/core/pylabtools.py in <lambda>(fig)
    246 
    247     if 'png' in formats:
--> 248         png_formatter.for_type(Figure, lambda fig: print_figure(fig, 'png', **kwargs))
    249     if 'retina' in formats or 'png2x' in formats:
    250         png_formatter.for_type(Figure, lambda fig: retina_figure(fig, **kwargs))

~/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/IPython/core/pylabtools.py in print_figure(fig, fmt, bbox_inches, **kwargs)
    130         FigureCanvasBase(fig)
    131 
--> 132     fig.canvas.print_figure(bytes_io, **kw)
    133     data = bytes_io.getvalue()
    134     if fmt == 'svg':

~/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/matplotlib/backend_bases.py in print_figure(self, filename, dpi, facecolor, edgecolor, orientation, format, bbox_inches, pad_inches, bbox_extra_artists, backend, **kwargs)
   2191                            else suppress())
   2192                     with ctx:
-> 2193                         self.figure.draw(renderer)
   2194 
   2195                     bbox_inches = self.figure.get_tightbbox(

~/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/matplotlib/artist.py in draw_wrapper(artist, renderer, *args, **kwargs)
     39                 renderer.start_filter()
     40 
---> 41             return draw(artist, renderer, *args, **kwargs)
     42         finally:
     43             if artist.get_agg_filter() is not None:

~/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/matplotlib/figure.py in draw(self, renderer)
   1861 
   1862             self.patch.draw(renderer)
-> 1863             mimage._draw_list_compositing_images(
   1864                 renderer, self, artists, self.suppressComposite)
   1865 

~/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/matplotlib/image.py in _draw_list_compositing_images(renderer, parent, artists, suppress_composite)
    129     if not_composite or not has_images:
    130         for a in artists:
--> 131             a.draw(renderer)
    132     else:
    133         # Composite any adjacent images together

~/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/matplotlib/artist.py in draw_wrapper(artist, renderer, *args, **kwargs)
     39                 renderer.start_filter()
     40 
---> 41             return draw(artist, renderer, *args, **kwargs)
     42         finally:
     43             if artist.get_agg_filter() is not None:

~/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/matplotlib/cbook/deprecation.py in wrapper(*inner_args, **inner_kwargs)
    409                          else deprecation_addendum,
    410                 **kwargs)
--> 411         return func(*inner_args, **inner_kwargs)
    412 
    413     return wrapper

~/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/matplotlib/axes/_base.py in draw(self, renderer, inframe)
   2745             renderer.stop_rasterizing()
   2746 
-> 2747         mimage._draw_list_compositing_images(renderer, self, artists)
   2748 
   2749         renderer.close_group('axes')

~/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/matplotlib/image.py in _draw_list_compositing_images(renderer, parent, artists, suppress_composite)
    129     if not_composite or not has_images:
    130         for a in artists:
--> 131             a.draw(renderer)
    132     else:
    133         # Composite any adjacent images together

~/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/matplotlib/artist.py in draw_wrapper(artist, renderer, *args, **kwargs)
     39                 renderer.start_filter()
     40 
---> 41             return draw(artist, renderer, *args, **kwargs)
     42         finally:
     43             if artist.get_agg_filter() is not None:

~/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/matplotlib/lines.py in draw(self, renderer)
    794             gc.set_antialiased(self._antialiased)
    795 
--> 796             ec_rgba = mcolors.to_rgba(
    797                 self.get_markeredgecolor(), self._alpha)
    798             fc_rgba = mcolors.to_rgba(

~/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/matplotlib/colors.py in to_rgba(c, alpha)
    187         rgba = None
    188     if rgba is None:  # Suppress exception chaining of cache lookup failure.
--> 189         rgba = _to_rgba_no_colorcycle(c, alpha)
    190         try:
    191             _colors_full_map.cache[c, alpha] = rgba

~/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/matplotlib/colors.py in _to_rgba_no_colorcycle(c, alpha)
    267         # Checks that don't work: `map(float, ...)`, `np.array(..., float)` and
    268         # `np.array(...).astype(float)` would all convert "0.5" to 0.5.
--> 269         raise ValueError(f"Invalid RGBA argument: {orig_c!r}")
    270     # Return a tuple to prevent the cached value from being modified.
    271     c = tuple(map(float, c))

ValueError: Invalid RGBA argument: array(['r', 'b', 'r'], dtype='<U1')

<Figure size 432x288 with 1 Axes>
```

Following some similar answers, I have tried:

- swapping out the `c` parameter for `color` -> no effect
- using `np.squeeze` on the color array -> no effect
- using a 2-d array for the color vector, with an array of rgb values instead of the string literals "r" and "b" or "red" and "green" -> no effect

Does anyone know how I can fix this while still using the `pyplot.plot()` function?

Thank you,

Paul

Comment: You're missing the `import matplotlib.pyplot as plt` line in your MWE, as well as whatever lines are defining `xCircle` and `yCircle` (do you mean to be plotting `xTest` and `yTest` instead?). Also, is there a reason you're not wanting to use `plt.scatter`? (You just need to add `marker=` in front of `"o"` to the function call and it will work).

Comment: Hi, sorry about that -- I was about to take it down and make that edit, and then I saw that @j1-lee had already responded, so I just edited as fast as I could... but apparently not fast enough. please see the above edit, where those issues are fixed.  I just tried your suggestion, and it worked! A bit strange, since I assumed they would have the same parameter formats. But its good to know this is possible with `plt.scatter`

Comment: You can't have `plot` plot a single series with multiple colors. You have to plot each one individually, e.g., `plt.plot(xTest[0],yTest[0],'o'+colorVec[0],xTest[1],yTest[1],'o'+colorVec[1],xTest[2],yTest[2],'o'+colorVec[2])`, or multiple lines of `plot` calls, or just use a loop. If you're repeating colors a lot, I'd suggest defining arrays of indices for each color, for example with a dict `cs = {'r': np.array([0,2]),'b':np.array([1])}`, and then do: `for c in cs: plt.plot(xTest[cs[c]], yTest[cs[c]], "o",c=c)` (though you'll have to declare `xTest` and `yTest` as arrays instead of lists)

Comment: `scatter` by default takes a third positional argument, `s`, which gives the marker size of the points, which is why the exact same formatting call won't work